# How to get form submission time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

How to capture google form response submit time into a variable and use it to insert to a MySQL table. I am using the code below but cannot capture it.

```
function getFormSubmitTime(){
 var form = FormApp.openById('dfsjfeifcnxzc121ii3ZZy'); 
 var formResponses = form.getResponses();
 var formResponse = formResponses[formResponses.length-1];
 var gettime = formResponse.getTimestamp();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are still quite a few things that you have to fill in because I don't know anything about your database.  But this will give you the timestamp value from your form submit and I've also provided boiler plate for a jdbc connection to your database.  You'll have to finish the INSERT statement for your database table. And of course you will also have setup the onFormSubmit trigger.

You can learn more about the onFormSubmit() event parameters [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) and JDBC [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/).

```
function myonFormSubmit(e) 
{
    var ts=e.values[0];
    runQuery("INSERT INTO `TABLENAME` (`timestamp`,....) VALUES ('ts')");
}


function runQuery(qry)//This is pretty bare bones as it has no error handling built in.  I removed it from a much more complicated function. Which you can find in the link in the text below.
{
    var address='address';  
    var user='user';
    var userPwd='pass';
    var db='db';
    var dbUrl='jdbc:mysql://' + address + '/' + db;
    var conn=Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
    var stmt=conn.prepareStatement(qry)
    stmt.execute();
}
```

If you have any trouble hooking up the JDBC connection your welcome to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46038582/7215091).